# Как определить, что view при анимации пересекает другое view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Есть анимированное view, которое двигается по вертикали, это view находится поверх таблицы. View по размеру меньше чем ячейка таблицы, как можно узнать, что view касается ячейки. Нужно сделать анимацию ячейки пока view касается данной ячейки.

Как определить, что view находится поверх ячейки?

```
CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:floor inSection:0]];
    CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [tableView convertRect: rectOfCellInTableView toView: [tableView superview]];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:labs(floorsBetween) * 2.0f delay:0.1f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        frame.origin.y = rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y + ((tableView.frame.size.height/7)-self.frame.size.height)/2;
        self.frame = frame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //completion
    }];
```

Comment: что то в коде не видно что с чем пересекаем. И еще бы точнее кто чей сабвью (это надо для перевода координат)

Comment: Оба view они subview self.view. А пересекаться должен self и  ячейка таблицы, от который известны координаты.

Comment: как self? вы этот код вызываете в том вью, который по экрану летит?

Comment: да, плохая идея так делать?

Comment: я бы сказал очень плохая. давайте все таки view controller будет осуществлять view control :)

Comment: Подождите, а откуда тогда у вашего летучего вью взялся референс на таблицу?

Comment: Передаю из класса, откуда вызываю метод

Comment: ладно, я думаю это тема для отдельного разговора, тем более что картинки :facepalm: тут все равно нет :)

Comment: сорри, еще зеленый совсем =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверить что вью пересекаются:

```
BOOL viewsIntersect = CGRectIntersectsRect(self.frame,
         [self.superview convertRect: [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]
                              toView: [tableView superview]);
```

чтобы все это работало во время анимации:

создать таймер

```
@property NSTimer *timer;
```

запустить апдейты по таймеру, когда анимация начинается

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(detectCollision) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

сравнивать фреймы (в этом случае надо для движущегося вью брать layer)

```
BOOL viewsIntersect = CGRectIntersectsRect([[self.layer presentationLayer] frame],
         [self.superview convertRect: [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]
                              toView: [tableView superview]);
```

остановить апдейты когда анимация кончилась

```
[self.timer invalidate];
```

Когда вью начали пересекаться, запускать нужную анимацию для таблицы, когда перестали пересекаться - останавливать ее.

Comment: Спасибо, при первой возможности попробуй переместить код в controller и добавить данный ответ в код. После отпишусь.

Comment: исправил ответ - фрейм надо проверять у presentationLayer не сам layer объекта

Answer (score 0):

Я Вам уже писал, что можно определить frame ячейки относительно и экрана, и таблица,

```
CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [tableView convertRect: rectOfCellInTableView toView: [tableView superview]];
```

Потом, Вы можете просто сравнивать frame вашей view, и ячейки, и из этого уже делать определенные действия.

Comment: Да, я это делал, но что-то не сработало. Я думаю, что проблема в том, что я не там вызываю метод, как можно отслеживать движение во время анимации? Использую `UIView animation`

Comment: Предоставьте больше кода пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @ИльяТерезников CGRectIntersectsRect(x,y);

Comment: CGRect frame = self.frame;
 frame.origin.y = rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y + ((tableView.frame.size.height/7)-self.frame.size.height)/2;
        self.frame = frame;
А где собственно вы задаете view этот frame?